# Lentidão com aumento constante, no emulador e carregamento da IDE

Tags: android-studio

Desde a instalação do `Android Studio`, o emulador constantemente vai ficando mais lento com o decorrer do uso, e não é por falta de excluir apps teste, etc, também a própria IDE começa a ter lentidão no carregamento de projetos.

Anteriormente eu usava `Windows 10`e hoje uso `Ubuntu 16`, claro que, Ubuntu ainda é melhor sem dúvidas, mas também estão começando a querer ficar lento.

Gostaria de saber se também repararam nisso, se tem alguma função "reset" do emulador ou da IDE que melhore o desempenho, ou alguma outra dica de melhoria ?

Comment: É normal o emulador ficar mais lento conforme o aumento do app que está fazendo, logo um app "Helow World" vai ser bem mais lento do que outro com a API do Google Maps. Se refere a isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não. O emulador com o tempo ele vai tendo uma lentidão independente do app. Mesmo se você excluir todos apps que foram instalados para teste, ele se mantém com uma certa lentidão para abrir, fechar, testar os apps.

Answer (score 0):

sim realmente começa a apresentar mais lentidão com o passar do tempo, isso infelizmente é normal, diretórios vão sendo criados, você fica com mais cache, memória RAM é mais consumida... enfim o que se pode fazer é amenizar o problema.

- criando emuladores mais fracos - *os testes ficam mais rapidos, não
  exige tanto da sua maquina virtual.*
- ativando o gradle Daemon no gradle.properties
  (org.gradle.daemon=true) - *O Daemon é um processo que roda em
  background e executa os builds de uma maneira mais rápida evitando
  processos de inicialização exaustivos e mantendo dados de seu projeto
  em cache.*
- agora uma coisa pessoal que faço é clicar a cada 10m no botão abaixo
  para diminuir a memoria alocada. esse botão se encontra no canto
  inferior direito.

[image: botão]

Comment: Caraca, nem lembrava mais desse tópico, não uso Android Studio faz MUITO tempo! rs Agora só VS Code! AS nunca mais! rs... mas valeu a resposta!

Comment: kkk dboa! faz 2 anos também né